# Cannot pull from mongoose array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema I have two arrays with users, invitedUsers and joinedUsers. Invited array is created from request body

```
invitedUsers: req.body.invitedUsers
```

Joined array is updated when user clicks 'Join'

```
$addToSet: {joinedUsers: req.user}
```

I can then pull user from joinedUsers array by performing

```
{$pull: {joinedUsers: {_id: req.user._id}}}
```

However, I can't pull from invited users array, although user object is the same. Here is the complete code:

```
app.put('/decline/events/:id', function (req, res) {
    var update = {$pull: {invitedUsers: {_id: req.user._id}}};
    console.log(req.user._id);

    Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, update, function (err, event) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        };

        Event.find({})
            .populate('owner')
            .exec(function (err, events) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                };
                res.json(events)
            });
    });
});
```

Ajax call on client

```
$scope.declineInvitation = function (id) {
        $http.put('/decline/events/' + id)
            .success(function (data) {
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

Everything goes without errors, but invitedArray doesn't change, as if mongoose fails to find it. What might be a solution to this?

**Update**

Event Schema definition, as requested:

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String, default: ''},
    startDate: Date,
    invitedUsers: {type: Array, default: []},
    joinedUsers: {type: Array, default: []},
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: null},
    location: String
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably because the `_id` in `invitedUsers` is a String and `req.user._id` is an ObjectId. Try `var update = {$pull: {invitedUsers: {_id: req.user._id.toString()}}};`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're defining `joinedUsers` as just an `Array` instead of an array of users like `[userSchema]`?  It should start working if you did that.

Comment: @victorkohl Thanks, toString does the trick, so the issue is closed

Comment: @JohnnyHK No particular reason, I was mostly just interested why $pull works with one array and fails with another.

Comment: @vitalym The reason I was asking is that defining a schema for it will take care of these sort of type conversion issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the `_id` in `invitedUsers` is a String and `req.user._id` is an ObjectId.

Calling `toString()` on `_id` will solve it:

```
var update = {$pull: {invitedUsers: {_id: req.user._id.toString()}}};
```